# QT theme in Clementine in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, qt, clementine

I have a strange problem with QT theme in Clementine. When it is run from sound menu (notification area), it has Windows classic theme:

[image: Clementine with Windows classic theme]

When it is run from terminal or Ubuntu menu, it looks OK:

[image: Clementine how it should look]

In both cases the 'clementine' process is run without any arguments.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here under Ubuntu 14.04. Workaround for me is to open Clementine from the Unity starter, or menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04, workaround it with qtconfig! run qtconfig and select GUI style GTK+

This GTK+ theme looks same as Ubuntu theme just some icons are different...